# How to show that a function of the form $e^{az+b}(e^{z}+z)$ cannot be a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to show that a function of the form $e^{az+b}(e^{z}+z)$ cannot be a polynomial? One way I can think of is to try to calculate the order of  $e^{az+b}(e^{z}+z)$, but I cannot find a way to calulate the order of it.

Comment: Have a look at $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^x}{x^n}$ for any $n$.  Successive  applications of L'Hospital's Rule suffices.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Show that at $+ \infty$ or $-\infty$, (or along the line if your function is complex) your function grows faster than $x^n$ for all $n$.